# Unions and intersections simplification ran into dead end

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
A \cup (C \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B \cap C) = A \cup (C \cap \overline{A}) \cup (A \cap B \cap C) = A \cup C \cup (A \cap B \cap C) = ??.
$$

I have got this far, but have no idea now to continue.

I hope someone who is more seasoned in propositional calculus can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just wondering why did you say that this is propositional calculus. (Of course this can be equivalently be written using $\lor,\land,\lnot,\to$ but you did write it in set form)

Comment: @Asaf : my native language isn't english, so I did not know what to call it the first place, but I found this on google and thought this was it. I guess I was mistaken. What is it called really?

Comment: I considered this as an option; the other one was that you were taught this in some logic relation course. I have edited the title and tags.

Comment: Well, since unions, intersection, and complements satisfy the same laws as $\vee$, $\wedge$, and $\neg$, namely the laws of Boolean algebra, we can call this propositional calculus, Boolean algebra, or unions and intersections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of $A$.  Hence $A\cup(A\cap B\cap C)=A$.
So $A\cup (C\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)=A\cup(C\setminus A)=A\cup C$.
You cannot reduce this further.